# Auto-detect language of file

Tags: file, programming-languages, auto

Is there a way to auto-detect the language that a file is written in or a way to say "this file is 20% C, 30% python, 50% shell." There must be some way because Github's remote server seems to autodetect languages. Also, if the file is a hybrid of languages, what is the de-facto way to set the file extension so that it represents those languages that are in the file. Maybe files have to all be homogeneous in regards to language. I am still learning. Additionally, is there a way to autodetect bytes of a codebase on a remote site like Github. So basically like Github's bar for languages except the bar shows how many bytes the project is taking up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `file` command on Linux does a reasonable job of guessing the language of a file, but basically it's just looking at the first characters of a file and comparing them to known situations: "if the file starts with blah-blah-blah it is probably thus-and-so".

As far as the file containing "20% C, 30% Python, etc" -- what would you do with such a file if you had one?  Neither the C compiler nor the Python compiler would be happy with it.

Answer (score -1):

I think Github uses file extensions to decide what language a code is written in.

As for auto-detecting file extension using the language, I suppose you could create a classification model.

You will have to create a large dataset with many files in different languages and their corresponding labels (language name). Then feed that training data to a neural network (maybe RNN-LSTM) to train the model. Then use that model on new data to predict language based on code.

I have never done something like this. But it would be a fun project.